I tried all answer of this question`React Native custom RefreshControl component doesn't work in FlatList on Android` But not work for me
const RefreshControlView = ({
  refreshing,
  onRefresh,
  children,
  ...props
}: RefreshControlViewProps) => {
  const theme: AppTheme = useTheme();
  const styles = getStyles(theme);
  return (
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={refreshing}
      onRefresh={onRefresh}
      tintColor={'transparent'}
      {...props}>
 {refreshing && (
        <LottieView
          source={require('src/assets/images/loader.json')}
          autoPlay
          loop
          style={styles.refreshLoader} // Adjust the size as needed
        />
      )}
 </RefreshControl>

This implementation works fine on iOS but on Android the FlatList items simply disappear, won't even show on the screen, but if I add directly the RefreshControl from the react-native will work.
How can I resolve this?
React Native custom RefreshControl component doesn't work in FlatList on Android
